# WPF Anti-aliasing edge of turned elements

Tags: wpf, antialiasing

I need **`Anti-alias`** edge of my turned rectangle more than normally.

My code is like this:

```
    <Rectangle Margin="20,20,147,135" Fill="#FFCAD2DE" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified">
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" ShadowDepth="2" Opacity=".5"/>
        </Rectangle.Effect>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="6" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
```

I change the angle slowly programmatically...

But the result is aliased in some angles like below image (left side). I want edge of my rectangle be **fully smooth** in all angles like the below image (right side).

[image]

---

**EDIT1:**

I use **.NET 3.5**

Comment: I think you'll have to provide a better code example. If I copy-paste your code into an empty WPF application, it is very much antialiased: http://imgur.com/smOP0JT

Comment: @vesan thank u for your test, use .Net 3.5 for your empty WPF application then rebuild the project and run... What you see? I wrote an answer. That steps helped me alot.

Comment: tested with .NET 3.5 and you're right, it looks a lot worse. Glad you found a solution, nice writeup in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps can help

---

### A)

First i moved my project from **.NET 3.5** to **.Net 4.5** without any changes in it and the result was:

> It looks like **very smoother**

---

### B)

**`Layout Rounding`**:

> [**What is `Layout Rounding` and how to use it in *WPF 4***](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3d6b7ec-71f9-4011-afc5-0bf3956e6d78/wpf-forum-faqs-updated-for-wpf-4?forum=wpf#x__Toc265507386)
>
> When an object edge falls in the middle of a pixel device, the
>   DPI-independent graphics system can create rendering artifacts, such
>   as blurry or semi-transparent edges.
>
> Previous versions of WPF included
>   pixel snapping to help handle this case. Silverlight 2 introduced
>   layout rounding, which is another way to move elements so that edges
>   fall on whole pixel boundaries.
>
> WPF now supports layout rounding with
>   the **`UseLayoutRounding`** attached property on `FrameworkElement`. Drawing
>   objects on pixel boundaries eliminates the semi-transparent edges that
>   are produced by anti-aliasing, when an edge falls in the middle of a
>   device pixel. When you use layout rounding, the layout system creates
>   small variations in the column or row measurements to avoid sub-pixel
>   rendering.

The following code uses **`UseLayoutRounding`** attached property set on a single pixel-width line. You can see the difference that layout rounding makes when you resize the window slowly.

```
<StackPanel Width="150" Margin="7" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <!-- Single pixel line with layout rounding turned OFF.-->
  <Rectangle UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="45.6" Margin="10" Height="1" Fill="Red"/>

  <!-- Single pixel line with layout rounding turned ON.-->
  <Rectangle UseLayoutRounding="True" Width="45.6" Margin="10" Height="1" Fill="Red"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

---

### C)

**`SnapsToDevicePixels`**

> **Note**
>
> You should set **`UseLayoutRounding`** to **true** on the **root
>   element**. The layout system adds child coordinates to the parent
>   coordinates; therefore, if the parent coordinates are not on a pixel
>   boundary, the child coordinates are also not on a pixel boundary.
>
> If `UseLayoutRounding` cannot be set at the root, set
>   **`SnapsToDevicePixels`** on the child to obtain the effect that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this isn't possible: [RotateTranform causes alias edges on border control or a Rectangle.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21e797fa-d516-4bd2-999b-5442a3f8652d/rotatetranform-causes-alias-edges-on-border-control-or-a-rectangle?forum=wpf)

From there:

> Fortunately, the edge becomes perfectly soomth for 25+ degree rotations on my computer. If you eventually find a way to solve your problem, please share with us. It will be very beneficial for other community members having the similar questions.